# SteamAPI Undefined index

Tags: php, steam-web-api

I'm a beginner in PHP and i am working with the steamapi. I got it figured out a bit and wanted to continue importing my current game in my site. Not i had the problem steam doesn't give anything when i use the steamapi and i'm not in game. When i am in game the code works fine (thats what i think thats going on).

To explain me a bit more:
When i am in game: `echo $json["response"]["players"][0]["gameextrainfo"];` --> this gives me the name of the game i am now in .

When i'm not in a game and i use: `echo $json["response"]["players"][0]["gameextrainfo"];` --> i get this Notice:

```
Undefined index: gameextrainfo in C:\xampp\htdocs\steam\steamapi.php on line 10
```

So i think the problem i am having is that when i'm not in a game steam returns nothing?

Can someone help me with this?

Like i said i'm just a beginner in PHP so if this is a dumb question i'm sorry.

Comment: Undefined index means that the array at $json['response']['players'][0] does not contain a key 'gameextrainfo'.

Which makes sense, you're not playing a game, so no extra info is given. You can check if a certain key is present using `array_key_exists("gameextrainfo", $json["response"]["players"][0])` or `isset($json["response"]["players"][0]["gameextrainfo"])`

Comment: @thisisboris so if i understand right this will give 1 if i'm in game and 0 if i'm not?

Comment: @thisisboris thank you so mutch this is what i searched for! Please provide your comment in an answer so i can accept it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undefined index means that the array at `$json['response']['players'][0]` does not contain a key `gameextrainfo`.

Which makes sense, you're not playing a game, so no extra info is given.

You can check if a certain key is present using

`array_key_exists("gameextrainfo", $json["response"]["players"][0])`

[PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

or

`isset($json["response"]["players"][0]["gameextrainfo"])`

[PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

In both cases it's assumed that there actually is a first player. You should check the steam-api to see which fields are always passed / always exist in the response.

Answer (score 0):

The steam api docs are at: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API

A pretty quick search under get player summaries returns:

> gameextrainfo If the user is currently in-game, this will be the name
>   of the game they are playing. This may be the name of a non-Steam game
>   shortcut.

API documentation can be pretty hard to parse when you are first starting out, but generally it is the best place to go for information. Hope that helps.

**--EDIT--**
In cases where you are not in game the information will not be returned, to account for this you should add in a check for the data before attempting to print it.

```
// Set variable for individual player
$playerInfo = $json['response']['players'][0];

// Test if extra info exists in player info array
if (array_key_exists('gameextrainfo', $playerInfo) 
  && !empty($playerInfo['gameextrainfo'])
) {
  // echo info string
  echo $playerInfo['gameextrainfo];
}
```

Comment: This was the site what i was using but i couldn't figure it out what to do if the steamapi returned nothing.

Comment: ahh, I didn't understand your question it sounded like you weren't sure whether you should be getting data or not.